# Got exception in Db health Ping clause in a Helidon application

Tags: postgresql, health-check, helidon

I updated my sample application to Helidon SE 2.1 and there is a ping statement for DB health:

```yaml
db:
 statement:
   ping: "select 1"
```

And I am using Postgres for test purpose.

But it did not work now. I got the exception when I accessing the `/health` endpoint.

```sh
{"ErrorClass":"java.util.concurrent.CompletionException",
"ErrorMessage":"org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected."}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ping is expecting DML statement by default. Try

```
DbClientHealthCheck.builder(dbClient)
        .query()
        .statementName("ping")
        .build();
```

to initialize healthcheck.

Also, this is going to be changed in 2.3.0, see https://github.com/oracle/helidon/pull/2656

Comment: I Hope Helidon can stabilize APIs as possible, every updates I will get some broken changes.